# what could cause the assembly instructions to change between compilation and actual runtime?

Tags: macos, compilation, clang, compiler-warnings

I wrote one function in c++ on MacOS M1 platform, it looks like this:

```cpp
off_t new_pos;
...
// some logic to manipulate new_pos like: new_pos = old_pos + off
...
if (new_pos < 0) {
  printf("new_pos is overflow");
  return -EINVAL;
}
...
...
```

After being compiled by clang, the generated code for the line `if (new_pos < 0) {` is (`tbnz x19, #0x3f, 0x100003cc8`), got by `otool -tvV a.out`.

but during running with lldb, I found that the code changed to:

```
cmn    x9, #0x2  
b.gt   0x100003dd0
```

(Obtained by reverse assembly by lldb)
The sematics of these two code fragments are different.

What caused this?

some other details:

```
Clang version:
    Apple clang version 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2.5)
    Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.4.0
        InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
Compile command:
    g++ -O3 xxx.cc -o xxx
```

The execution phenomenon I encountered:

under my input for the function, `new_pos` should become -9223372036854775808, so `if (new_pos < 0)`  will become true and print the overflow log in its clause.

If I compiled with O0, the overflow log was printed as expected;
If I compiled with O3, the overflow log was not printed as expected.
It was a little strange, so I disassemble the binary, then I found the above phenomenon.
I'm very wondering what has happened?